# Authorization with cookie - ROBLOX API

Tags: api, authorization, roblox, bubble.io

So Im trying to get a list of transactions from a group, but not sure how to implement the .ROBLOSECURITY cookie value into my header.[image]

Comment: Heyo, please don't just post pictures of your setup and errors. Please include the code that you have tried, and transcribe any errors you have gotten.

Comment: Its literally a no code platform.. not sure where you want me to get code from

Comment: Got me there I guess

Answer (score 0):

So the `.ROBLOSECURITY` is a cookie therefore it is assigned in the headers.

The way this should be used is:

- Header = `Cookie`
- Value = `.ROBLOSECURITY=your cookie`

Here is an example built in PostMan, not sure what your using:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I just tried it out and it still gave me an unauthorized error. Heres a recording: https://vimeo.com/785585757